# How to get child element of another child of the same parent with jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, parent

I have an input box that generates a bunch of `div`s using jQuery. Inside each div, there are more divs including an a link. When the user clicks that a element, I want an alert box to show the html of another div inside of the same main div. See code below.

**HTML**

---

```
<form rol="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="s" id="s-label">Please enter the id below</label>
        <input class="form-control text-center" type="input" id="s" onkeyup="getS( $( this ).val() );">
    </div>
</form>

<div class="col-md-12" id="s-results">
</div>
```

**jQuery (This is an AJAX call)**

---

```
function getS(sS) { 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 's-query.php',
    mimeType: 'json',
    //dataType: 'application/json',
    data: {sku: sS},
    success: function(data) {
        var disp = "";

        counterp = 0;
        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
            disp += "<div class='col-md-12' id='sDisplay'>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-2' id='dSku' >" + data[0] + "</div>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-3' id='dDesc'>" + data[1] + "</div>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-2' id='dMast'>" + data[2] + "</div>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-2 text-center'>";
            disp += "<input class='col-md-6 text-center' type='number' value='"+ data[3] + "' id='dChange'>";
            disp += "</div>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-2 text-center'>" + data[4] + "</div>";
            disp += "<div class='col-md-1 text-center'><a class='inv-click' id='" + counterp + "' onclick='updateD(this.id)'  value='" + counterp + "'><i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i></a></div>";
            disp += "</div>";

            counterp = counterp + 1;
        });

        //Success function if all goes well.
        $( "#sku-results" ).empty();

        $( "#s-results" ).append( disp );

    },
    error: function() {
        alert('There seems to be an error fetching the data.');
    }
  });
}

function updateD(getId)
{
    var par = $( "#" + getId ).closest("skuDisplay").children("dMast").html();
    alert(par);
}
```

The result of the jQuery populates the `s-results` div to come out to be something along the lines of this...

```
12345 | Item 1 | 2,680 | 195 | 123-456 | update (<-this is the a element)
98765 | Item 2 | 2,680 | 45  | 987-653 | update
74185 | Item 3 | 2,680 | 330 | 645-852 | update
...
```

...where each row is a parent div (`skuDisplay`), and each "column" or value in the row is it's own div inside of the parent div.

In this example, every time someone clicks on the a element in each div, I want an alert box to show the corresponding div inside the same div as the a element with the id `dMast`. In the example above, using `.html()`, when I click on the a element, the alert box just displays `undefined`, even though the html inside of the `dMast` div is *2,680*.

I've tried to replace `html()`, or something in that line, with the following, with no luck:

`-var par = $( "#" + getId ).closest("skuDisplay").children("dMast").val();`

`-var par = $( "#" + getId ).parent("skuDisplay").children("dMast").text();`

`-var par = $( "#" + getId ).parent().children("dMast").html();`

How would I obtain the html of divs inside of the same parent as the a element that was clicked?

Comment: `.closest("skuDisplay")`, `.children("dMast")` everywhere, missing something? And you don't need to traverse DOM when selecting element by id, provided id is unique on page, and it should.

Comment: Same for `.closest("skuDisplay")` and `.parent("skuDisplay")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$( "#skuDisplay #dMast" ).html 
in other words first put the parent then put the child the parent can be written as a .class or #id

Comment: I'm unclear where you are suggesting I place my answer. The a tag that triggers the function I am running doesn't have a form. Can you clarify?

Comment: i cont test it but try ("#skuDisplay div") i think you might have forgoton the id of sku display ("#skuDisplay #dmast") or what you are doing before might also work with id #

Comment: Great catch. That was a clumsy oversight. Thank you. Works exactly as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

your missing the #id for skudisplay and dmast